# avd window lost its border

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Ubuntu 22.04, Android Studio 2023.3.1 Patch 2.
When I boot the avd, it seems like this:

[image]

But after I do something in the avd, it become like this:

[image]

As you can see, it lost its border, so I cannot drag it to change the position of the window. But after I change avd to the landscape mode, the border appear again and never disappear anymore, until I close and reboot it.
Why does it happened?

I try to remove the avd and create a new one, and remove the emulator tools in Android Studio SDK manager and reinstall it, but they don't work. I try to search some information in the Internet, but I cannot find anything related to this.

---

Well, now I have found that when I change the API version of my avd from API 34 to API 31, the problem disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason of this problem. I use another computer that the android studio is out of date and there isn't any problem. But when I update the API34 system image to the revision 9, the problem occurs. So maybe it is just a little bug in the new revision.